# How to enable button after user filed all the textfields in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I am doing Swift iOS application. In that, I have some signup screen. In that, I have 3 textfields.
My requirement is user should not allowed double space and if textfield is empty, user should be restricted single space too. If there is even single character in textfield, user can able to give single space.

But, once all 3 textfields filled, then only I have to enable **Done** button, but even single textfield is empty, I have to disable that Done button.

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let rawString = string
        let range = rawString.rangeOfCharacter(from: .whitespaces)
        if ((textField.text?.count)! == 0 && range  != nil)
            || ((textField.text?.count)! > 0 && textField.text?.last  == " " && range != nil)  {
            return false
        }

        self.doneButtonEnable()
        return true
    }

  func doneButtonEnable()  {
      if ((firstNameTextField.text!.count > 0) && (lastNameTextField.text!.count > 0) && (displayNameTextField.text!.count > 0)) {
          doneButtonAppearance(appearance: true)
          doneButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"image_enable"), for: .normal)
      } else {
          doneButtonAppearance(appearance: false)
          doneButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"image_disabled"), for: .normal)
      }
  }
```

The issue is, If I enter single character in all 3 textfields each textfield with 1 character, button is still showing disabled and if I enter 2 characters in last textfield then only Done button enabling.

Also if I removed total text in 3rd textfield, It should disable Done button, but, In console it is showing last character of last entered text.

This is the issue I am facing.

Any solutions?

Comment: why you are returning false ?

Comment: @jawadAli where?

Comment: in `shouldChangeCharactersIn` function ...

Comment: I am disabling single and double space if there is no text, and if there is any text, and enabling single text and disabling double space.

Comment: so what issue you are facing ?

Comment: I have added issue in bottom of the question, Please check once

Comment: it is not that clear to me

Comment: sorry for that, But, What I am facing issue is explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you call `self.doneButtonEnable()` before textField done while you edit. Mean you input 's' in func 'shouldChangeCharactersIn' at `self.doneButtonEnable()` line, textField.text does not add 's' to its text. So just delay this function. Try below code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
     self.doneButtonEnable()
}
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much!!